# Routerlink is not working, but I can go to the view if I enter path in url

Tags: angular6

In my main route, I have many modules, some lazyloading, others are preloading strategy, also I have routes for simple components. Some routes have AuthGuard.

When I click in an element with a Routerlink, it goes to Authguard but it stops there, the view is not loaded, and the url doesn't change.

If I enter the route in the url works and the page loads correctly.

app.module.ts

```js
           import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
        import { NgModule, LOCALE_ID, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA, Injectable, Injector, Inject, InjectionToken, ErrorHandler } from '@angular/core';
        import { registerLocaleData, CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
        import { HttpClientModule, HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http';
        import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
        import localeEsArs from '@angular/common/locales/es-AR';
        
        import { ToasterModule, ToasterService } from 'angular2-toaster';
        
        registerLocaleData(localeEsArs);
        
        import { environment } from '../environments/environment';
        
        import { routing } from './app.routing';
        
        //Components and Services
        import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
        import { CallbackComponent } from './callback.component';
        import { DisableControlDirective } from './directives/disable.directive';
        
        import { AuthGuard } from './auth.guard';
        import { EventEmitterService } from './services/event.emitter.service';
        import { GenericModal } from './modals/genericmodal/modal.component';
        
        import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
        
        //services
        import { AuthService } from './services/auth.service';
        import { UserService } from './services/user.service';
        import { BookingService } from './services/booking.service';
        
        //Material Angular
        import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
        import { MatInputModule, MatFormFieldModule, MatExpansionModule, MatDividerModule, MatTableModule, MatButtonModule,
          MatMenuModule, MatSelectModule, MatSidenavModule, MatIconModule, MatToolbarModule, MatCheckboxModule,
          MatTabsModule, MatPaginatorModule, MatButtonToggleModule, MatDialogModule, MatAutocompleteModule, MatNativeDateModule,
          MatProgressSpinnerModule, MatTableDataSource, MatListModule, MatSliderModule, MatProgressBarModule, MatSlideToggleModule,
          MatStepperModule, MatRadioModule, MatCardModule, MatBadgeModule
        } from '@angular/material';
        
        import { UserMetadataAdapter } from './core/adapter/userMetadataAdapter';
        import { PlaceAdapter } from './core/adapter/placeAdapter';
        import { CalendarAdapter } from './core/adapter/calendarAdapter';
        import { PlaceGoogleAdapter } from './core/adapter/placeGoogleAdapter';
        import { PredictionAdapter } from './core/adapter/predictionAdapter';
        import { FingerPrintsAdapter } from './core/adapter/fingerPrintsAdapter';
        import { GoogleAnalyticsService } from './services/googleAnalytics.Service';
        import { SimpleAlgorithms } from './core/algorithms/simpleAlgorithms';
        import { About } from './about/about.component';
        import { PageNotFoundComponent } from './error/page-not-found/page-not-found.component';
        import { DragToSelectModule } from 'ngx-drag-to-select';
        
        
        import { InfiniteScrollModule } from 'ngx-infinite-scroll';
        
        
        
        import { ReviewAdapter } from './core/adapter/reviewAdapter';
        import { UserAdapter } from './core/adapter/userAdapter';
        
        import { CookieService } from './services/cookieService';
        import { ConfirmationDialog } from './entities/shared/dialogs/confirmation-dialog/confirmation-dialog';
        import { BlogComponent } from './blog/blog.component';
        import { BlogPostComponent } from './blog-post/blog-post.component';
        import { CurrencyAdapter } from './core/adapter/currencyAdapter';
        import { BellNotifyComponent } from './bell-notify/bell-notify.component';
        import { NotificationAdapter } from './core/adapter/notificationAdapter';
        import { OnScrollLoadComponent } from './shared/onscroll-load/onscroll-load.component';
        import { SafePipe } from './pipes/safe.pipe';
        import { MapLoaderModule } from './loaders/map/map-loader.module';
        import { CroppingLoaderModule, GlobalVariables } from './loaders/cropping/cropping-loader.module';
        import { UserActivityLogService } from './services/activitylog/user-activity-log.service';
        import { UserActivityLogAdapter } from './core/adapter/activity-log/userActivityLogAdapter';
        import { DialogTermsAndCondOverview } from './new-place-module/new-place/new-place.component';
        import { BusinessInfoService } from './services/businessInfo.service';
        import { PostAdapter } from './core/adapter/postAdapter';
        import { EmitterService } from './services/emitter.service';
        import { DateTimeService } from './services/datetime/date-time.service';
        import { HomeModule } from './home-module/home.module';
        import { AppCustomPreloader } from './app-custom-preloading';
        import { HttpErrorInterceptor } from './http-error-interceptor';
        
        // Rollbar Init----------------------------------------------------------
        import Rollbar from 'rollbar';
        import { NotificationService } from './services/notification/notification.service';
        import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
        import { Help } from './help/help.component';
        
        const rollbarConfig = {
          accessToken: environment.rollbarLog.accessToken,
          captureUncaught: true,
          captureUnhandledRejections: true,
          environment: environment.rollbarLog.envName
        };
        
        export const RollbarService = new InjectionToken<Rollbar>('rollbar');
        
        @Injectable()
        export class RollbarErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler {
          constructor(@Inject(RollbarService) private rollbar: Rollbar) { }
        
          handleError(err: any): void {
            if (environment.production)
              this.rollbar.error(err.originalError || err);
          }
        }
        
        export function rollbarFactory() {
          return new Rollbar(rollbarConfig);
        }
        
        //Rollbar End-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        
        @NgModule({
          exports: [
            MatInputModule,
            MatFormFieldModule,
            MatExpansionModule,
            MatDividerModule,
            MatTableModule,
            MatButtonModule,
            MatMenuModule,
            MatSelectModule,
            MatSidenavModule,
            MatIconModule,
            MatToolbarModule,
            MatToolbarModule,
            MatCheckboxModule,
            MatButtonToggleModule,
            MatTabsModule,
            MatPaginatorModule,
            MatDialogModule,
            MatAutocompleteModule,
            MatNativeDateModule,
            MatProgressSpinnerModule,
            MatListModule,
            MatSliderModule,
            MatProgressBarModule,
            MatSlideToggleModule,
            MatStepperModule,
            MatRadioModule,
            MatCardModule,
            MatBadgeModule
          ]
        })
        export class MaterialAngularModules { }
        
        @NgModule({
          declarations: [
            AppComponent,
            DisableControlDirective,
            CallbackComponent,
            GenericModal,
            PageNotFoundComponent,
            About,
            Help,
            ConfirmationDialog,
            BlogComponent,
            BlogPostComponent,
            BellNotifyComponent,
            OnScrollLoadComponent,
            DialogTermsAndCondOverview
          ],
          entryComponents: [GenericModal, ConfirmationDialog, DialogTermsAndCondOverview],
          imports: [
            BrowserModule,
            BrowserAnimationsModule,
            MaterialAngularModules,
            HttpClientModule,
            CommonModule,
            FormsModule,
            RouterModule,
            ReactiveFormsModule,
            MatCheckboxModule,
            routing,
            CroppingLoaderModule,
            DragToSelectModule.forRoot(),
            InfiniteScrollModule,
            ToasterModule.forRoot(),
            MapLoaderModule,
            NgbModule,
            HomeModule
          ],
          exports: [],
          providers: [{ provide: LOCALE_ID, useValue: 'es-AR' }, AuthService, AuthGuard, EventEmitterService, EmitterService, GoogleAnalyticsService,
            UserMetadataAdapter, PlaceAdapter, CalendarAdapter, PlaceGoogleAdapter, PredictionAdapter, FingerPrintsAdapter, SimpleAlgorithms, ReviewAdapter,
            UserAdapter, UserService, UserActivityLogService, CookieService, NotificationService, BusinessInfoService, CurrencyAdapter, NotificationAdapter,
            UserActivityLogAdapter, PostAdapter, AppCustomPreloader, DateTimeService,
            {
        
              provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
        
              useClass: HttpErrorInterceptor,
        
              multi: true
        
            },
            { provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: RollbarErrorHandler  },
            { provide: RollbarService, useFactory: rollbarFactory }
          ],
          schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA],
          bootstrap: [AppComponent]
          
        })
        export class AppModule { }
```

app.route.ts

```
  
        import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
        import { Routes, RouterModule, PreloadAllModules } from '@angular/router';
        import { ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core';
        import { AuthGuard } from './auth.guard'; 
        import { CallbackComponent } from './callback.component';
        import { About } from './about/about.component';
        import { PageNotFoundComponent } from './error/page-not-found/page-not-found.component';
        import { BlogComponent } from './blog/blog.component';
        import { BlogPostComponent } from './blog-post/blog-post.component';
        import { HomeComponent } from './home-module/home/home.component';
        import { AppCustomPreloader } from './app-custom-preloading';
        import { Help } from './help/help.component';
        
        export const routesApp: Routes = [
          { path: '', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: 'home' },
          {
            path: 'home',
            component: HomeComponent
          },
          //{
          //  path: 'main',
          //  component: AppComponent
          //},
          {
            path: 'callback',
            component: CallbackComponent
          },
          {
            path: 'place/:id',
            loadChildren: './place-module/place.module#PlaceModule',
            data: { preload: false }
          },
          {
            path: 'login',
            loadChildren: './authentication-module/authentication.module#AuthenticationModule',
            data: { preload: true }
          },
          {
            path: 'place-account',
            loadChildren: './place-account-module/place-account.module#PlaceAccountModule'
          },
          {
            path: 'reports',
            loadChildren: './report-module/report.module#ReportModule'
          },
          {
            path: 'new-place',
            loadChildren: './new-place-module/new-place.module#NewPlaceModule',
            data: { preload: true }
          },
          {
            path: 'mybooking',
            loadChildren: './place-booking-module/place-booking.module#PlaceBookingModule'
          },
          {
            path: 'user-booking',
            loadChildren: './user-booking-module/user-booking.module#UserBookingModule',
            data: { preload: true }
          },
          {
            path: 'my-account',
              loadChildren: './user-account-module/user-account.module#UserAccountModule'
          },
          {
            path: 'blog',
            component: BlogComponent
          },
          {
            path: 'blog-post/:id',
            component: BlogPostComponent
          },
          {
            path: 'place-creditandnotify',
            loadChildren: './place-credit-and-notification-module/place-credit-and-notification.module#PlaceCreditAndNotificationModule'
          },
          {
            path: 'about',
            component: About
          },
          {
            path: 'help',
            component: Help
          },
          {
            component: PageNotFoundComponent,
            path: "404",
          },
          {
            path: "**",
            redirectTo: '404'
          }
        ];
        
        export const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(routesApp, {
          preloadingStrategy: AppCustomPreloader
        });
```

home.module.ts

```js
        import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
        import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
        import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
        import { homerouting } from './home.routing';
        
        import {
          MatFormFieldModule, MatTabsModule, MatInputModule, MatIconModule, MatAutocompleteModule, MatSelectModule,
          MatCheckboxModule, MatButtonToggleModule, MatSliderModule, MatSlideToggleModule
        } from '@angular/material';
        import { MapLoaderModule } from '../loaders/map/map-loader.module';
        import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
        import { PlaceListComponent } from './home/place-list/place-list.component';
        import { PlaceBoxComponent } from './home/place-box/place-box.component';
        import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
        import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
        
        
        @NgModule({
          exports: [
            MatFormFieldModule, MatTabsModule, MatInputModule, MatIconModule, MatAutocompleteModule, MatSelectModule,
            MatCheckboxModule, MatButtonToggleModule, MatSlideToggleModule, MatSliderModule
          ]
        })
        export class MaterialAngularModules { }
        
        @NgModule({
          entryComponents: [],
          imports: [
            CommonModule,
            FormsModule,
            ReactiveFormsModule,
            MaterialAngularModules,
            homerouting,
            MapLoaderModule,
            NgbModule
          ],
          declarations: [
            HomeComponent,
            PlaceListComponent,
            PlaceBoxComponent
          ],
          exports: [
            HomeComponent
          ]
        })
        
        export class HomeModule { }
```

app.component.html

```html
    <!--<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Titillium+Web&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">-->
    <!--  -->
    
    <div class="router-container noScroll" >
    
      
    
      <mat-sidenav-container class="example-sidenav-container">
    
        <mat-sidenav #snav>
    
          <!-- <p id="nameAuth" *ngIf="authService.isLoggedIn()">{{authService.getName()}}</p>
      <div *ngIf="authService.isLoggedIn()" class="nameAuth">{{authService.getName()}}</div>
            -->
          <p class="menu-boton"><button (click)="snav.close()" routerLink="/home" mat-button  [ngClass]="(document.location.pathname=='/home')?'button-left-panel': 'button-left-panel-noactive'">Home</button></p>
          <p class="menu-boton"><button (click)="snav.close()" routerLink="/about" mat-button  [ngClass]="(document.location.pathname=='/about')?'button-left-panel': 'button-left-panel-noactive'">Nosotros</button></p>
          <p class="menu-boton"><button (click)="snav.close()" routerLink="/blog" mat-button  [ngClass]="(document.location.pathname=='/blog')?'button-left-panel': 'button-left-panel-noactive'">Blog</button></p>
          <p class="menu-boton"><button (click)="snav.close()" routerLink="/ayuda" mat-button [ngClass]="(document.location.pathname=='/ayuda')?'button-left-panel': 'button-left-panel-noactive'">Ayuda</button></p>
    
    
    
          <div *ngIf="authService.isLoggedIn() && hasPlace">
            <mat-divider></mat-divider>
            <p class="menu-boton">Mi Negocio</p>
            <p class="menu-boton"><button (click)="snav.close()" routerLink="/place-account" mat-button  [ngClass]="(document.location.pathname=='/place-account')?'button-left-panel': 'button-left-panel-noactive'">Mi Lugar</button></p>
            <p class="menu-boton"><button (click)="snav.close()" routerLink="/mybooking" mat-button  [ngClass]="(document.location.pathname=='/mybooking')?'button-left-panel': 'button-left-panel-noactive'">Mi Calendario</button></p>
            <p class="menu-boton"><button (click)="snav.close()" routerLink="/place-creditandnotify" mat-button  [ngClass]="(document.location.pathname=='/place-creditandnotify')?'button-left-panel': 'button-left-panel-noactive'">Creditos</button></p>
            <p class="menu-boton"><button (click)="snav.close()" routerLink="/reports" mat-button  [ngClass]="(document.location.pathname=='/reports')?'button-left-panel': 'button-left-panel-noactive'">Reportes</button></p>
          </div>
    
          <div>
            <p class="menu-boton"><button (click)="snav.close()" *ngIf="!authService.isLoggedIn()" routerLink="/login" mat-button [ngClass]="(document.location.pathname=='/login')?'button-left-panel': 'button-left-panel-noactive'">Iniciar sesion</button></p>
          </div>
    
          <div *ngIf="authService.isLoggedIn()">
            <mat-divider></mat-divider>
            <a style="margin-top:30px;" class="header-menu">
              <div class="user-picture-url" style="cursor: pointer;">
                <img style="width:35px;height:35px;" [src]="userProfileImage != null ? userProfileImage : ''" alt="">
                {{name}}
                <div class="header-menu" (click)="modal.show(); snav.close()" (mouseclick)="modal.show()">
                  <mat-icon [matBadge]="unreadMessages" matBadgeColor="warn">notifications</mat-icon>
                </div>
              </div>
            </a>
    
            <p class="menu-boton"><button (click)="snav.close()" routerLink="/my-account" mat-button [ngClass]="(document.location.pathname=='/my-account')?'button-left-panel': 'button-left-panel-noactive'">Mi Cuenta</button></p>
            <p class="menu-boton"><button (click)="snav.close()" routerLink="/user-booking" [ngClass]="(document.location.pathname=='/user-booking')?'button-left-panel': 'button-left-panel-noactive'" mat-button>Mis reservas</button></p>
            <p class="menu-boton"><button (click)="authService.logout()" mat-button>Log Out</button></p>
    
          </div>
    
          <div *ngIf="authService.isLoggedIn() && !hasPlace">
            <mat-divider></mat-divider>
            <p class="menu-boton"><button (click)="snav.close()" style="margin-top:25px; padding-left:20px;padding-right:20px;" routerLink="/new-place" mat-button [ngClass]="(document.location.pathname=='/new-place')?'button-left-panel': 'button-left-panel-noactive'">Agrega tu espacio</button></p>
          </div>
    
        </mat-sidenav>
    
        <mat-sidenav-content>
          <mat-toolbar color="primary" class="example-toolbar">
            <img routerLink="/home" style="outline: none; border: 0; cursor: pointer;" [src]="fullImagePath" class="img-logo">
    
            <ul class="menu-upi">
    
              <li><a class="header-menu" routerLink="/home">Home</a></li>
              <li><a class="header-menu" routerLink="/about">Nosotros</a></li>
              <li><a class="header-menu" [routerLink]="['/blog']" routerLinkActive="active">Blog</a></li>
              <li><a class="header-menu" routerLink="/help">Ayuda</a></li>
    
            </ul>
    
            <!--
        <form class="search-form">
          <mat-form-field class="search-width">
            <input matInput placeholder="Find a place" [formControl]="searchFormControl">
            <mat-error *ngIf="searchFormControl.hasError('email') && !searchFormControl.hasError('required')">
              Please enter a valid email address
            </mat-error>
          </mat-form-field>
        </form>
         -->
            <!--<a *ngIf="!authService.isLoggedIn()" (click)="authService.login()">Log In</a>-->
    
            <div class="header-widget">
              <!--<a (click)="login()" class="header-menu popup-with-zoom-anim">google</a>
          <a (click)="authService.signup('venturinosaporta@gmail.com', 'Ventuu3040')" class="header-menu popup-with-zoom-anim">Registrarse</a>-->
              <!--<a *ngIf="!authService.isLoggedIn()" (click)="authService.login()" class="header-menu popup-with-zoom-anim">Iniciar sesion</a>-->
              <p class="menu-usuario">
                <img *ngIf="!userHasLoaded && !error" [src]="loadingImagePath" style="width:15%; float:right" />
              </p>
              <ul class="menu-usuario" *ngIf="userHasLoaded && !error">
                <li *ngIf="authService.isLoggedIn() && hasPlace">
                  <a class="header-menu" style="cursor: pointer;" [matMenuTriggerFor]="menuempresa">Mi negocio</a>
                  <mat-menu #menuempresa="matMenu" [overlapTrigger]="false">
                    <p class="menu-boton"><button routerLink="/place-account" mat-button [ngClass]="{'button-left-panel': router.url=='/place-account'}" >Mi Lugar</button></p>
                    <p class="menu-boton"><button [routerLink]="['/mybooking']" mat-button>Mi Calendario</button></p>
                    <p class="menu-boton"><button routerLink="/place-creditandnotify" mat-button>Creditos</button></p>
                    <p class="menu-boton"><button routerLink="/reports" mat-button>Reportes</button></p>
                  </mat-menu>
                </li>
                <li *ngIf="authService.isLoggedIn()">
    
                  <a style="margin-top:30px;" class="header-menu" [matMenuTriggerFor]="menuuser">
                    <div class="user-picture-url" style="cursor: pointer;">
                      <img style="width:35px;height:35px;" [src]="userProfileImage != null ? userProfileImage : ''" alt="">
                      {{name}}
                    </div>
                  </a>
    
                  <mat-menu #menuuser="matMenu" [overlapTrigger]="false">
                    <p class="menu-boton"><button routerLink="/my-account"  *ngIf="authService.isLoggedIn()" mat-button>Mi Cuenta</button></p>
                    <p class="menu-boton"><button routerLink="/user-booking" *ngIf="authService.isLoggedIn()" mat-button>Mis Reservas</button></p>
                    <p class="menu-boton"><button *ngIf="authService.isLoggedIn()" mat-button (click)="authService.logout()">Log Out</button></p>
                  </mat-menu>
                </li>
                <li *ngIf="authService.isLoggedIn()">
                  <div class="header-menu" style="cursor: pointer;" (click)="modal.show()" (mouseclick)="modal.show()">
                    <mat-icon [matBadge]="unreadMessages" matBadgeColor="warn">notifications</mat-icon>
                    <!-- Include text description of the icon's meaning for screen-readers -->
    
                  </div>
                </li>
    
                <li>
                  <a class="header-menu" *ngIf="!authService.isLoggedIn()" routerLink="/login">Iniciar sesion</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <label class="header-menu popup-with-zoom-anim" *ngIf="authService.isLoggedIn() && mobileQuery.matches">{{authService.getName()}}</label>
                  <a *ngIf="authService.isLoggedIn() && !hasPlace" style="margin-top:25px; padding-left:20px;padding-right:20px;" routerLink="/new-place" class="button border header-menu">Agrega tu espacio </a>
                </li>
    
              </ul>
              <div *ngIf="error" style="color: black; text-align: right; margin-top: 15px">
                <button (click)="window.location.reload()">
                  <span class="material-icons">
                    loop
                  </span>
                  Refrescar
                </button>
              </div>
            </div>
    
    
            <button class="menu-mobile" mat-icon-button (click)="snav.toggle()"><mat-icon>menu</mat-icon></button>
    
          </mat-toolbar>
          <div [hidden]="!loadingModule" style="position:fixed; margin-top:25%; margin-left: 50%;">
            <h2>Loading...</h2>
            <mat-progress-bar mode="indeterminate"></mat-progress-bar>
          </div>
          <div [hidden]="loadingModule" >
            <router-outlet></router-outlet>
          </div>
        </mat-sidenav-content>
      </mat-sidenav-container>
    </div>
    
    <toaster-container [toasterconfig]="config"></toaster-container>
    
    <app-bell-notify #modal style="cursor: pointer;" (numberOfNotificationsEmiter)="getNumberOfNotificationsUnread($event)">
      <div class="app-modal-header">
        Notificaciones
      </div>
      <div class="app-modal-body">
        Whatever content you like, form fields, anything
      </div>
      <div class="app-modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="simple-button" (click)="modal.hide()">Close</button>
      </div>
    </app-bell-notify>
```

MapLoaderModule

```js
    import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
    import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
    import { BrowserModule } from "@angular/platform-browser";
    import { MapComponent } from "src/app/map/map.component";
    import { AgmCoreModule, GoogleMapsAPIWrapper } from '@agm/core';
    import { AgmSnazzyInfoWindowModule } from '@agm/snazzy-info-window';
    import { AgmJsMarkerClustererModule } from '@agm/js-marker-clusterer';
    import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
    
    
    @NgModule({
      imports: [
        CommonModule,
        AgmCoreModule.forRoot({ apiKey: 'AIzaSyB23x4UGHNZ-YRDCM1rI-AcdQ6lTyQcdyo' }),
        AgmJsMarkerClustererModule,
        AgmSnazzyInfoWindowModule,
        RouterModule
      ],
      exports: [MapComponent],
      declarations: [MapComponent],
      providers: [GoogleMapsAPIWrapper]
    })
    export class MapLoaderModule {}
```

Comment: Did you  added  in `app-routing.module.ts` in the imports array 

 `@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})`

before exporting the class `AppRoutingModule`?

and `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` in app.component.html?

Comment: Update your router links with this one. hope that this will work fine

`<li>
    <a class="header-menu" [routerLink] = "['/home']" >HOME</a> 
  </li>`

Comment: Yes, I have imported routes like this and I have router-outlet in app.component

Comment: Did you update your routerLinks?

Comment: I've tried writing the routerlink in this format as you can see in the first image.

Comment: try  this one in your route file i could not see routerLink for home  `<li>     <a class="header-menu"  [routerLink] = "['/callback']" >Call Back </a>    </li>`

if still issue not solved please share your code with  `stackblitz`?  so we can help.

Comment: callback is in another module, this is why is not in app.component. I will try to reproduce it in stackblitz! thanks

Comment: No problem with your `routerLinks` in HTML every format works fine. 

you can test here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-router-basic-example-yqjw84?file=app/app.routing.module.ts

Comment: I updated the code. I added the Home module. 
When I enter to a module/view from url (ex. http://localhost/place/2), it works. Then, from this place view, routerlinks (routerlinks are in app.component) start working. The issue is when I'm in home view. In HomeModule I removed the RouterModule, but this wasn't the issue. I don't know what could be breaking the routerlink in Home view. I will continue debugging.

Comment: In my Home.module.ts I imported a MapLoaderModule, which is a module for a  single component (.ts, .html, .css). In this MapLoaderModule, I imported RouterModule because I'm using RouterLink. The RouterLink in the MapLoaderModule (This module is basically google maps), works fine, but this RouterModule in MapLoaderModule breaks others Roterlinks in the HomeModule...I tried different combinations, adding or removing RouterModule with no luck. The good news is that I found the root cause.

Comment: I added the MapLoaderModule in the post. 
The MapLoaderModule  has been imported in HomeModule.
If I remove the RouterModule from MapLoaderModule, the routerlink in HomeModule works, but inside the MapLoaderModule component throws an error because it does not recognize the routerlink . If I add the RuterModule in MapLoaderModule, in HomeModule, all routerlink stop working, but works in MapLoaderModule.....

Answer (score 0):

Remove the / on `routerLink`

`routerLink='home'` same for the rest

Comment: Hi. I got the same behavior. It goes to authguard with the correct "state.url" and then nothing happens.

Comment: try to edit your post to show us the complete code and not with images

Comment: Hi, I 've updated the code. I tried with different formats of routerlink like [routerLink]="['/mybooking']".  Again, when I click in one of this, it goes to authguard with the correct route, but then stops. In the authGuard I put a "return true" in the "canActivate"... Also I'm getting the same behavior with routerlink to simple components with no AuthGuard...

Comment: At your place.modulets declare in imports routesApp and HomeComponent at declarations. Also remove the / from routerLink at the HTML (I have always used without the /)

Answer (score 0):

Was missing the import RouterModule  in MapLoaderModule

```
const mapRoutes: Routes = [
];

export const maprouting: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forChild(mapRoutes);
```

I don't need to route in this module, so I leave empty